# How do I change a String Array (being read from a text file) to a Int Array? So that I can search and sort the data

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int, system.io.file

I'm reading several text files in which I need to search and sort the data, searching and sorting isn't the issue as I've done this with some previous code. However, what I cannot seem to do is get my program to change the string array made from the file to an int array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried tryparse, bool, decimal, int, int32 etc. I'm relatively new to c# so please don't pass these off as a definite that they won't work, as they more than likely will... Just I haven't figured out how...

```
//Reads Files
            string Low256 = "Low_256.txt";
            string[] LowString256 = File.ReadAllLines(Low256);
            string High256 = "High_256.txt";
            string[] HighString256 = File.ReadAllLines(High256);
            string Mean256 = "Mean_256.txt";
            string[] MeanString256 = File.ReadAllLines(Mean256);

//Removes Spaces from the txt file
            int i = 0;
            int[] LowArray256 = new int[256];
            foreach (string line in LowString256)
                if (line != " ")
                {
                    LowString256[256] = line;
                    i++;
                }
            int[] HighArray256 = new int[256];
            foreach (string line in LowString256)
                if (line != " ")
                {
                    LowString256[256] = line;
                    i++;
                }
            int[] MeanArray256 = new int[256];
            foreach (string line in LowString256)
                if (line != " ")
                {
                    LowString256[256] = line;
                    i++;
                }

//Converts Strings Arrays To Int 
            LowArray256 = Array.ConvertAll(LowString256, Int32.Parse);
            HighArray256 = Array.ConvertAll(HighString256, Int32.Parse);
            MeanArray256 = Array.ConvertAll(MeanString256, Int32.Parse);
```

Error received is System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

the expected result is to be able to use the int array to search and sort through the data.

*EDIT*

The files consist of data such as...

16.8614

15.3207

18.3596

17.1516

15.5238

18.4468

19.2638

17.0751

... in this very format with a space and a new line character after each number.
The document itself cannot be edited.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of the file content, please? Anything we suggest will depend entirely on the data in the files.

Comment: "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" -- there are some strings in your string array which cannot be parsed. Inspect the array's content looking for values not being a valid integer representation.

Comment: There seems to be numerous problems with this code, but the most important lacking part is a sample from the file, so that we can see what you're actually trying to process. Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: As an example of those "numerous problems", did you really intend to write to the 257th entry of a 256-entry array? That would give an array index out of bounds exception, which is in addition to your parsing problems.

Comment: The fact that you're posting about a parsing problem, where, if the current structure code is supposed to be correct, the code would actually never get to, tells me that this is not your actual code (the writing to the 257th entry in a 256-entry array happens before the conversion/parsing). Can you please provide an [mcve], or at the very least your *actual* code?

Comment: Apologies, @JayV and Lasse, I've edited my question to show an example of the file.

The code itself is mine, but I'm relatively new to any coding in general, not just coding c#, so it doesn't 100% all make sense to me.

Comment: Your file probably isn't exactly what the computer expects, e.g. it contains a blank line ("" isn't a valid integer) or a null terminator character, that sort of thing. It's not always a code issue. The simplest thing would be to debug the program (step through it) and inspect the string variables just before they are converted. You may be surprised by what you see.

Comment: @JohnWu what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the files contain a number every row:

```
            //Read files
            string Low256 = "Low_256.txt";
            string[] LowString256 = File.ReadAllLines(Low256);
            string High256 = "High_256.txt";
            string[] HighString256 = File.ReadAllLines(High256);
            string Mean256 = "Mean_256.txt";
            string[] MeanString256 = File.ReadAllLines(Mean256);

            //Convert string[] to int[]
            int[] Low256Int = new int[LowString256.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < LowString256.Length; i++)
            {
                int.TryParse(LowString256[i], out int parsed);
                Low256Int[i] = parsed;
            }

            int[] Mean256Int = new int[MeanString256.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < MeanString256.Length; i++)
            {
                int.TryParse(MeanString256[i], out int parsed);
                Mean256Int[i] = parsed;
            }

            int[] High256Int = new int[HighString256.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < HighString256.Length; i++)
            {
                int.TryParse(HighString256[i], out int parsed);
                High256Int[i] = parsed;
            }
```

Comment: This line... 'Error received is System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'' suggests that some of these won't be convertible to an int. The way you've done it risks encountering the same exception and you haven't handled that exception.

Comment: Now the code ignores invalid strings but I don't think this is better. In my opinion if a file which is meant to store only valid data has an invalid data in it, it should throw an exception.